# Colocar comillas en función paste R

Tags: r, string, concatenación

Estoy utilizando la función paste en R, pero estoy recibiendo un resultado no esperado, ejemplo:

```
paste('texto1"','texto2"',sep = "")
```

El resultado es:

> "texto1\"texto2\""

El resultado esperado sería:

> "texto1"texto2""

No entiendo bien de donde aparece el caracter `\`.

Gracias por el apoyo, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

En realidad la barra invertida en `\"` está, pero no está.

En R el símbolo `"` es un caracter reservado, es muy importante porque sirve para delimitar cadenas de caracteres. Cuando R se encuentra uno lo entiende como el inicio de un string o cadena de caracteres, entonces para poder usarlo como un string propiamente dicho es necesario indicarle a R que no lo trate como el símbolo reservado `"`, sino como la cadena de caracteres `'"'`. La manera de hacerlo es "escapando" el caracter y en R, como en otros lenguajes, el símbolo que con el que se escapa un caracter reservado es la barra invertida. En tu caso la función `paste()` hace automáticamente ese escape: detecta que la cadena de caracteres está delimitada con `' '` y que el `"` que está adentro no la está cerrando, sino que es simplemente un caracter. El método print que lo muestra en pantalla agrega, por algún motivo, el `\` detrás, pero estrictamente hablando para R es como si no existiera.

A manera de prueba:

```
'\"' == '"' #Regresa TRUE, son exactamente iguales. 
paste('"') == '"' #También regresa TRUE
paste('texto1"','texto2"',sep = "") == 'texto1"texto2"' #TRUE

cat(paste('texto1"','texto2"',sep = ""))  #cat saca directo a consola la cadena
texto1"texto2"  #Desaparecen las barras invertidas

knitr::kable(data.frame(a = '\"')) #Digamos que estoy generando una tabla, aquí tampoco se imprime \

|a  |
|:--|
|"  |
```

En síntesis:

1. internamente R lo maneja así para no confundir un delimitador de la cadena de caracteres de un elemento de la cadena de caracteres.
2. Dependiendo del método con el que se imprima en pantalla aparece o no aparece `\`, pero no debería preocuparte mucho, más allá de la molestia visual.